# ¿Cómo cojo unas filas y columnas determinadas de un CSV con Awk?

Tags: csv, shell-script, awk

En mi script tengo que hacer que utilizando Awk al escribir lo siguiente:

```
read year
```

coja el contenido de esa variable "year" y me salga en pantalla todas las filas que tengan el mismo número que he introducido.

Este es un ejemplo de mi documento:

```
title   rating  ratinglevel ratingdescription   release_year    user_rating_score   user_rating_size
Breaking Bad    TV-MA   For mature audiences. May not be suitable for children 17 and under.    110 2013    97  80
The Vampire Diaries TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  2017    91  80
The Walking Dead    TV-MA   For mature audiences. May not be suitable for children 17 and under.    110 2015    98  80
Pretty Little Liars TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  2016    96  80
Once Upon a Time    TV-PG   Parental guidance suggested. May not be suitable for all children.  70  2016    98  80
Sherlock    TV-14   Parents strongly cautioned. May be unsuitable for children ages 14 and under.   90  2016    95  80
```

En concreto lo que busco es que al introducir el año, me salgan las películas/series que sean de ese mismo año y que de todas las que me salgan simplemente salgan la primera y segunda celda.

Mi expected output si introduzco el año 2016 sería:

```
Pretty Little Liars , TV-14
Once Upon a Time , TV-PG    
Sherlock , TV-14
```

Comment: Pero el ejemplo que pusiste no parece ser un csv

Comment: ¿Cuál es el delimitador de las columnas? ¿Qué intentaste?

Answer (score 2):

Por empezar, el ejemplo que muestras no parece un CSV ya que no se distingue el caracter que separa cada columna, lo que me hace pensar que se trate de un tab (`\t`), si este fuera el caso, puede hacer un sencillo script `awk`:

```
gawk -F'\t' '$5==2016 {print $1 ", " $2}' tu_archivo.txt
```

De cualquier forma puedes usar `-F<caracter>` para definir el separador de columna, con `$5==2016` filtramos los casos dónde la quinta columna sea el valor `2016` (`==`: valor exacto `~`: expresión regular), en cuyo caso, hacemos `{print $1 ", " $2}`, imprimimos primera y segunda columna.

Comment: @fedorqui, buena acotación